# HTTP 403 error when fetching data from Google Classroom API with Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, google-classroom

I made an iOS app (Swift) that signs in with Google, then fetches classroom data from the (Google Classroom API) https://developers.google.com/classroom. Everything was working correctly, and then some time later I think I accidentally deleted the Google Cloud project associated with it. So I had to re-create it and recreate an OAuth Client ID (I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) guide on Google's website).

Now I'm getting an https status code 403 error - [Permission Denied](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Access.Errors) while trying to fetch classes, and I have no idea why. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

I believe the specific error (according to the Google Classroom API error section, linked above) is:

[image]

...but I'm very confused what to do to fix this.

One thing that is interesting is when I created an OAuth Client ID and downloaded the `credential.plist` (or credential**s** - can't remember) file and inserted it into the Xcode project, I get the same error as when the .plist file is not there. I'm wondering if I have it named something incorrectly? (Because before I had an entire `GoogleService-Info.plist` file since I had an associated Firebase project), but now that I don't need the firebase project anymore, I just have the credentials in the downloaded plist file which inherently is called `credentials.plist`.

**Edit** One strange thing is that I am only trying to read data, so I don't know why it's telling me I attempted to modify data.

Comment: Strangely enough, this error magically went away after a few days... My production app that is live in the App Store was throwing this error for several days, and then suddenly the error went away completely. I didn't even submit any new update! So that was weird...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some of the API to manage the classwork from the students with the Classroom API, you could be affected by this [alert](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-classwork#manage_student_responses):

[image]

This could be interpreted in a way that, all the CourseWork that was managed by the previous Client ID is basically linked to that Client ID. This also has been discussed over the public issue tracker when it comes to Classwork created from the normal UI and how it can be managed:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67748271#comment8

I would suggest to also share some feedback for this feature request so it gets the attention it needs. I notice that features like this for Classroom have been approved and implemented due to the high amount of users utilizing Classroom, generally it was previously limited however it has since been getting great support.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue because I am only trying to read data, I am not modifying anything. Any other thoughts?

Comment: The new GCP project has the Classroom API enabled and also if your organization has enabled the API access for Classroom data over the Admin console if you are using Google Workspace.